# launch a process from asp.net website and execute it

Tags: asp.net

from a web page on a server I would like to :

visit a webpage.
enter my credentials.

click go and execute a program .exe on the server.
This program runs a robocopy .bat file that mirrors my dlls.

Is this possible?

I am using Process.Start with the .exe as the file name. I can get the credentials right, but it never really executes. It may be because it was a click once app.

Does anyone have any experience with this? am i going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Does it throw any kind of error such as permissions or can't find the exe?

Comment: there are many tutorials on how to run exe on server, and many questions on SO on the same subject.

Comment: It throws no errors, but the file action does not occur.